# Correct parameters on php sendmail?

Tags: php, email

thats my mail.php:

```
<?php

$empfaenger = "thisisatest@me.com";
$betreff = "Test";
$from = "From: Test <test@me.com>";
$text = "Erfolg!";

mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $text, $from);

?>
```

Now i want to call this mail function out of a html and post a value (like a text) into the mail function. How do i have to call the mail function with the parameters correctly?

Is it possible to call the mail function out of my html like this?:

```
variable="test";
sendmail($variable);
```

Comment: you can write your own function called `sendmail()` which wraps `mail()` - i think that's what you are asking. you can add any number of arguments to `sendmail()` that you need

Comment: Okay .. thats my sendmail:

var sendMail = function(data){

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail.php",
      data: "zahler=5",
      success: function(response) {
        console.log('success: ',response);
      },
    });
}

Comment: How do i post a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *call* PHP directly from HTML without using it's proper syntax. So to answer your question: no. Also, in PHP, you don't declare variables without the dollar sign. Else then that, what you're actually asking is very unclear.

To transmit form data, you would have to use the HTML tag `<form>` and the PHP `$_GET` or `$_POST`. Google these concepts online to learn further on them, they are very fundamental.